# Error when running PySimpleGUI code through linux terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

My python code runs smoothly when I run it through Thonny python IDE but when I try to run it through the linux command terminal this error show up.

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":10.0"

I am using PySimpleGUI for the GUI part of my code. Any help on how to run a GUI through the linux terminal would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share with us how to you actually run the code inside your terminal.

Comment: Are you running it through the Windows Subsystem for Linux terminal? Or are you using an actual linux OS?